# TypeError: Can't concat bytes to str indexing API

Tags: python, google-api, urllib2

I am trying to use the google indexing API using python but keep getting the following error:

```
 'TypeError: Can't concat bytes to str'
```

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
SCOPES = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" ]
ENDPOINT = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish"
JSON_KEY_FILE = "json_key.json"

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSON_KEY_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

content = {"url" : "https://careers.google.com/jobs/google/technical-writer",
            "type" : "URL_UPDATED"
            }

response, content = http.request(ENDPOINT, method="POST", body=content)
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The following line causes the issue, because body expects `byte` but you provide a `dict` instead:

```
response, content = http.request(ENDPOINT, method="POST", body=content)
```

To fix the issue, you need to encode `content` to JSON and finally cast it to `byte`:

```
response, content = http.request(ENDPOINT, method="POST", body=bytes(json.dumps(content))
```